# Intel desktop mothermoard with integrated graphic. Showing LVDS n VGA, that i cant configure

Tags: 12.04, resolution, intel, vga

Have Intel motherboard.
Graphics integrated. Ubuntu 12.04 showing to monitors, LVDS n VGA connected, but I have only VGA. And Ubuntu think that my monitor can show FullHD but really it can only 1280*1024. And VGA display was automatically configured to 1280*1024, LVDS - FullHD. And I can see just left half screen  on a display.
When I'm trying to disconnect LVDS - have a black screen.
When I'm trying configure any resolution on any of this displays have an error or black screen randomly.
xrandr and manipulation with it, couldn’t help, just a black screen

Once I'm trying to set 1024*768 on VGA display and have a normal screen but very big fonts and icons. 
In BIOS i can only turn off integated graphic and LVDS. But on motherboard no any PCI or PCI-Ex.

So I wanna set resolution to 1280*1024.

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood what you have tried correctly, but this is the kind of line you are probably looking for....

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --off --output VGA1 --mode 1280x1024
```

Comment: Sorry for my english. But I tried this before, and get a black screen.